# Deserialize to object with custom object property

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a class like so:

```
public class CareTaker
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public DateTime? DateTrained {get; set;}
    public Certification Certification {get; set;}
    public List<Certification> ExpiredCertifications {get; set;}
}

public class Certification
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

and my JSON is like so:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dogtor",
    "dateTrained": "01 Feb 2017",
    "certification": 2,
    "expiredCertifications": [1,5]
}
```

I know usually the JSON for `Certification` should really be like `"certification": { "id": 2}`, but, I don't have access to change the JSON so I have to figure out how to convert what I recieve (`"certification": 2`) to my object... Is there a way I can do this with either [JavascriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) please?

Comment: Change your code to `public List<int> expiredCertifications { get; set; }` and parse it to your `Certification` class later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public class CareTaker
{
    ...
    [NotMapped]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "certification"]
    public int? CertificationId
    {
        get
        {
             return Certification?.Id;
        }
        set
        {
           Certification = new Certification { Id = value; }
        }
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Certification Certification {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, that's a great way to solve this problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

To generate properly the classes, I would suggest copying the JSON and open the file where you want to store the classes and in visual studio go to EDIT->Paste Special->Paste JSON As Classes

then you would do something like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonToClasses = ser.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Sorry, changing the object is not an option either, they're pre existing EF models and I cannot change neither the JSON nor the models - I've had this same discussion with my TL and manager several time already; I have to work with this unfortunately!

Comment: Okay, so instead of the RootObject you would use CareTaker